# What is the time complexity of a size() call on a LinkedList in Java?

Tags: java, size, linked-list, time-complexity

As the title asks, I wonder if the size() method in the LinkedList class takes amortized O(1) time or O(n) time.

Comment: Note, for concurrent structures computing size may be slow, and is pointless anyway.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It's O(1). You can google for the source code and you will come to such:

From http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html

All of the Collection classes I have looked at store a the size as a variable and don't iterate through everything to get it.

Comment: ctrl-click in NetBeans will find it even faster than google ;)

Answer (score 18):

O(1) as you would have found had you looked at the source code...

From LinkedList:

```
private transient int size = 0;
```

...

```
/**
 * Returns the number of elements in this list.
 *
 * @return the number of elements in this list
 */
public int size() {
   return size;
}
```

Comment: And if you're not using Sun's implementation at all? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Class_Library#Alternative_implementations
I think his question is whether it is guaranteed to be O(1), rather than whether it is O(1) in any specific implementation/version.

Comment: The implementation has been the same since 1.2 when LinkedList was introduced, so it'll always be O(1)

Comment: This is from Java 1.6. This is not dependent on the VM but (in theory) could be different in older versions of the standard library. Check your version's source if you want to be 100% sure, but no sane developer would calculate the size on demand for something like this where everything is in memory and you can tally it up as the structure is created.