# How does `Java` `List` method `size` work?

Tags: java, list

In Java, there is a `List` interface and `size()` method to compute the size of the `List`.

- When I call `List.size()`, how does it count?
- Is it counted linearly, or the count is determined and just the value is returned back when `size()`?

Comment: its not linear. its O(1). just found here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863469/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-a-size-call-on-a-linkedlist-in-java

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Size is defined as the number of elements in the list. The implementation does not specify how the size() member function operates (iterate over members, return stored count, etc), as List is an interface and not an implementation.

In general, most concrete List implementations will store their current count locally, making size O(1) and not O(n)

Comment: +1 - last sentence is definitely true for the three general purpose list classes ArrayList, CopyOnWriteArrayList and LinkedList.

Answer (score 7):

[`java.util.List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an interface, not a class. The implementation of the [`size()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size()) method may be different for different concrete implementations. A reasonable implementation for a [`size()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size()) method on a [`java.util.List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementation would be to initialize an instance member of type `int` to zero and increment/decrement it appropriately as items are added to/removed from the [`List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html). The [`size()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size()) method could simply return the aforementioned instance member. This is of course, simply an example. For complete detail, you could always look at the sources for the built-in [`List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementations. All the source code has been available for years.

Comment: This is a case where I really favor the .NET naming conventions, using the prefix of "I" for interfaces.

Comment: @dalle: I find the `I` prefix to be hungarian noise. java programmers generally know that `List` (and `Map` and `Set` and `Collection`, etc.) are interfaces. On the other hand, many interfaces in java use the `able` suffix. eg. `Serializable`, `Cloneable`, `Iterable`, etc. So I guess java is not internally consistent either...

Comment: "For complete detail, you could always look at the sources for the built-in List implementations."  This is good advice that will serve you well in your career. And sometimes if the source code isn't available I'll even decompile to get the answer.