# Time complexity for size call on a linked list in ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity

I'm a newbie to ruby. Pardon me for asking such a simple question.

While I know that **Ruby doesn’t include a LinkedList class so we need to create our own**, therefore I created my own class as shown below:

```ruby
class Node
    attr_accessor :data, :next
    def initialize(data, next_node = nil)   
        @data = data
        @next = next_node
    end
end

class Linkedlist

    def empty?
        @head == nil  
    end

    def size
        count = 0
        if self.empty?
            return count
        else
            current_node = @head
            while current_node.next !=nil
                count += 1
                current_node = current_node.next
            end
            return count
        end
    end
        
    ...
    ...

    def add
        if self.empty?
            @head = Node.new(data)
        else
            while current_node.next != nil
                current_node = current_node.next
            end
            current_node.next = Node.new(data)
        end
    end
end
```

My implementation for `size` call clearly shows a time complexity of `O(n)`. while looking at the `Java` implementation in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/863496/22124677), it seems `Java` keeps a track of size of the `linked list` such that time complexity for size call is `O(1)`.

How do I make this possible using `ruby`?

Comment: Take a closer look at the [implementation](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html) you’re referring to and you’ll see `size++` and `size--` calls. That’s how the size is update and you can use the same logic in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `attr_accessor :size` to your `Class Linkedlist` and manipulate `size` in your `add` method like below:

```ruby
class Linkedlist
    attr_accessor :size

    def add
        if self.empty?
            @head = Node.new(data)
        else
            while current_node.next != nil
                current_node = current_node.next
            end
            current_node.next = Node.new(data)
        end
        modify_size("add")
    end

    def remove
        .
        . 
        # after removing node
        modify_size("remove")
        return removed_node
    end

    def modify_size(arg)
        case arg
        when 'add'
            self.size += 1
        when 'remove'
            self.size -= 1
        else
        end
    end

end

l1 = Linkedlist.new.add(1)
puts l1.size
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `size` implementation has complexity of `O(n)` because it iterates the whole list when calculating the `size`.

Instead, you could store the current `size` in an instance variable and increment that variable when you add a new node. With the current size being stored in an instance variable. The `size` method will return in `O(1)`.

```
class LinkedList
  attr_reader :size

  def initialize
    @size = 0
  end

  def add(data)
    if empty?
      @head = Node.new(data)
    else
      current_node = head
      current_node = current_node.next while current_node.next

      current_node.next = Node.new(data)
    end

    @size += 1
  end

  def empty?
    size.zero?
  end
    
  private

  attr_reader :head
end

list = LinkedList.new

list.add(:a)
list.add(:b)
list.add(:c)

list.size
#=> 3
```

When you are implementing a `remove` method, then that method will need to decrement the `@size` variable.

Note: I reformatted and rewrote some of your code to follow common Ruby idioms.

Comment: Further suggestion: if you're going to "cheat" for constant runtimes on common linked list operations, store the _last_ node in the linked list such that `add` can be a O(1) operation.